# jQuery: Temporarily change a style then reset to original class

Tags: jquery, css

Say I have a class named testThing:

```
.testThing
{
   background-color:#000000;
   float:left;
   height:50px;
   width:50px;
}
```

And I want to be able to test a background color change to whatever control is of that class on a button click:

```
function setColor(someColor) 
{
   jQuery('.testThing').css('background-color', someColor);
}
```

But I want the user to be able to reset to the original color (another button click) based on what the class has:

```
function resetClass()
{
   jQuery('#currentColor').removeClass('testThing');
   jQuery('#currentColor').addClass('testThing');
}
```

Seems like this would work (Albiet not the best way to do this) but the control's background color doesn't reset to the original value held in that class.

Now either I need to figure out why that remove to add doesn't reset it OR just a plain better way of doing it... seeing as it seems silly to remove and readd the class...

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery(...), you can just use $(..)

Comment: You do if there are multiple libraries being used like Microsoft's ajax thing or prototype.  I just do in case even though most likely I'll only use jquery.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Jquery adds CSS in the style attribute which has higher priority over what is in your CSS file. You're not changing your CSS document with that function and thus adding and removing and adding the class have no effect since it hasn't been modified at all!

You should use the same function but set the background color to black this time.

```
function reset(this)
{
  $(this).css('background-color', '#000000');
}
```

Or simply remove the style attribute

```
function reset(this)
{
  $(this).removeAttr('style');
}
```

Comment: this only works if you don't have other style settings you want to kepe

Comment: Well it clears every modification made with Jquery, which is exactly what he wanted here. He could still use the first one though.

Comment: remember that removeAttribute() isn't working anymore for jquery instead use removeAttr()!

Comment: But this removes any Styles on the element, effectively making it white! The OP asked how to restore the original style. Why not temporarily store the original style in a fake element ID and restore it from there later? What if the element is an alternate row in a gridview which has different colors every 2nd row?

Comment: @Fandango68 and anyone else concerned, this worked perfectly for my case. It does not remove `user agent` styles, it only removes styles applied to the element specifically as an attribute to that element (AKA styles applied through Javascript, or any in-line styling)

Comment: @EthanMoore - correct. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 129):

I know this is old, but you can just set the value to an empty string to remove your custom style like so:

```
// set
$(this).css('background-color', '#000000');

// reset
$(this).css('background-color', '');
```

Comment: Thanks jscheel!  This works very nicely and doesn't destroy other (previously existing) styles.

Comment: Still useful asf. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

What about `toggleClass("testThing")`? I use it when there's more than one property to change.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: I don't understand why this is the ultimate answer. I found this answer useful when we have a complex css to apply only for a specific conditions that need to be reset right after.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. I said the same thing you are: this is useful when you want to change more than one CSS property at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, I read my comment once again and found mistake. It's 'why this isn't the ultimate answer'. Not 'why this is the...'.

Answer (score 2):

It is better to just add another class that overrides the style you want to change and then remove it. It beats hard coding style info inside the js.
The only issue is youll have to ensure the added class is of a higher order so that the element takes the style from it rather than the existing class but this is not hard to ensure.

Comment: You could always use !important to make sure the attributes of your new class get taken.

Comment: nah I dont like using that, defeats the purpose of css imo

Comment: I have to agree that it does kind of break the rules though.

Comment: AND - !important is not compatible with some modern browsers :(