# Can i load css from the original file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Seems like to me there should be an option for that but i can't seem to find it.

This question was asked many times but only workarounds were answered and that's not what i'm looking for.

I am changing my css incode and i want to load the original css back instead of coding it myself, how can that be achived?

I don't wanna reload the **entire** file, just load some div or class css.

Comment: Maybe [check this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053418/jquery-temporarily-change-a-style-then-reset-to-original-class)

Comment: Thanks but it will only work with class, not div.. i need mostly div i guess

Comment: Check out the **answer**, not the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053418/jquery-temporarily-change-a-style-then-reset-to-original-class) for a solution.

Based on that you can do something like this:

```
$("#fix").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("div").removeAttr("style");
});​
```

Note: This assumes you are using JQuery to change the styles in the first place

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/TkV6J/1/)

Comment: This answering the op's question, didn't it?

Comment: @eric.itzhak: Well then perhaps you are not applying the old ones using css? My example clearly works... which browser are you using?

Comment: well I am, i think at least, i'm trying to get back the browsers default css for that element. and i'm appying with jQuerys "css" method so it should work.. i'm using Chrome

Comment: I too use Chrome, does the example JSFiddle I provided work for you? We need to work out what is different from your code

Answer (score 1):

if you're using jQuery apply

```
$(selector).removeAttr('style')
```

to your elements

Comment: I like this answer better, it's simplier, it doesn't assume any elements nor events it just does the job and it's up to the op where to use it...

Comment: This just removed the style, and didn't re-apply the old one. could it be related that my element is dynamically added?

Comment: no, should work perfectly fine. the command removes all styles that are applied via javascript or are hardcoded in the tag, but keeps all styles that are defined in CSS files, or with `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to load the original css back instead of coding it myself

This is not necessary.  You are trying to reload a resource that should just continue to exist.  Once it's loaded, you don't need to load it again.  If you need to override a style, apply a class to it.  To revert to original, remove the class.  That's how cascading style sheets work.

If there is a particular reason the css needs to be dynamic, you can try loading css into the Document via the DOM (`document.createElement("style")` etc.), but support for this is a bit sketchy I believe.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to reset the WHOLE style and not only divs' you'd better use the [`all selector`](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)

```
$('*').removeAttr('style');
```