# And how to click on the same button to return everything back?

Tags: javascript, onclick, return-value, display

When the button is clicked, I change the values of the display to the elements, change the color and the values of the input.

```
var deleteMarkerButton = document.getElementById('deleteMarkerButton');
var chooseMarkerDelete = document.getElementsByClassName('choose-marker__delete');
var chooseMarkerCheckbox = document.getElementsByClassName('choose-marker__checkbox');
var changeBasketColor = document.getElementsByClassName('cls-2');

    deleteMarkerButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < chooseMarkerDelete.length; i++) chooseMarkerDelete[i].style.display = 'block';
        for (var a = 0; a < chooseMarkerCheckbox.length; a++) chooseMarkerCheckbox[a].style.display = 'none';
        for (var b = 0; b < changeBasketColor.length; b++) changeBasketColor[b].style.fill = '#3c8bca';
        document.getElementById("addDeleteBtn").value = "Удалить";
    });
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I think the question is in the title. "How to click on the same button to return everything back."

Comment: Please change the title of your question to something that makes sense. Here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053418/jquery-temporarily-change-a-style-then-reset-to-original-class

Comment: @RayKoren that's a clear duplicate, marking. Possible duplicate of: [jQuery: Temporarily change a style then reset to original class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053418/jquery-temporarily-change-a-style-then-reset-to-original-class)  Good find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're always toggling between the same two values, this is trivial: just check to see what the current value is, and replace it with the other value.  Pseudocode `if (foo === a) {foo = b} else {foo = a}`

If you need to be able to revert to the original values after changing something, and the original values aren't known ahead of time, then you need to store those original values somewhere before changing them.

Below is a simplified example of one way to do this.

This toggles an element's `style.display`.  The current value is stored in a data attribute on the element before it's modified; that way the next time you click, the function can check the data attribute to see what the previous value was:

```js
var foo = document.getElementById("foo");
var bar = document.getElementById("bar");


foo.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // check to see if we've already stashed a value here:
  var pastValue = bar.getAttribute("data-display");

  // stash the current value:
  bar.setAttribute("data-display", bar.style.display);

  // set the current style to the stashed value, if there is one, or "none" otherwise:
  bar.style.display = pastValue || "none";
});
```

```html
<div id="foo">Click me</div>
<!-- the inline style is used here because `.style.display` can only read inline rules -->
<div id="bar" style="display:block">This will be toggled</div>
```